# Why does the images not come one after another?

Tags: html, css

I want to have the divs with class image-1 inline within the div having class of image-wrapper.
But I have tried a lot but the divs with class image-1 are not getting inline.
May i know where am i doing the mistake??

```
<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#666;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow-x:hidden;
 }
.image-wrapper{
    width:300%;
    height:390px;
    background-color:#000;
 }
.image-1{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#03F;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image-1">
        </div>
        <div class="image-1">
        </div>
        <div class="image-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the `float:left` from  the image-1 elements

2) Set `white-space:nowrap;` on the image-wrapper

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gqagbfj5/2/)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-wrapper {
  height: 390px;
  background-color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.image-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #03F;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image-1 + .image-1 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
.image-1 + .image-1 + .image-1 {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image-1">
    </div>
    <div class="image-1">
    </div>
    <div class="image-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs with `class="image-1"` has width set to 100% of their parent element (`class="image-wrapper"`).

If you want to float three images/divs, set them `width: 33.3%` (of parent width).

Example, with numbers:

```
.wrapper has width 300px
.image-wrapper has width 900px (300% of 300px)
.image-1 has width 900px (100% of 900px above)
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bg8mw53/

I set there wrappers width to 20% (because I want to show you how it´s really works, you can return back 100% there) and commented overflow, for the same reason. You can return this property back.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `width` of `.image-1` to `33.3%`. The width is calculated related to parent which in this case is `.image-wrapper`.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3xc2a5e/)

Answer (score 0):

Total Width of child divs exceed the width of parent divs.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }
.wrapper{  
 }
.image-wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
.image-1{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:5px;
 }
```

fiddle[here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5q6at6s/)